# Pass a prop from component to stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a badge rendered on the icon component of a bottom tab bar. The badge should be corresponding to the length of data I receive from an async call inside the screen. How do I send the bottomTabNavigator the length of the async call, which is called inside the screen

I tried dispatching an event like so, when responseJson is returned:

```
 const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
              params: { badge: responseJson.length },
            });
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction);
```

but when I get the navigation param from navigation options within the creation of the route in the createMaterialBottomTabBar, the navigation state is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: You have to set the key property of the NavigationAction to your route, and then access it in navigation.state routes directly